# What to do if setTimeout doesn't give any output

Tags: javascript, settimeout, telegram-bot, telegraf

I'm writing a telegram bot (using Telegraf) and need to send 3 messages in a particular order with some time intervals. Then I run this code in VC code, it works perfectly. When I deploy the same code on the server (AWS), it just doesn't work. I don't get any output from setTimeout functions.

```
const executeAfterGivenTime = (func, time) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(func()), time));

function newOne(ctx){
    ctx.reply('coo');
}

function newTwo(ctx){
    ctx.reply('boo');
}

function newThree(ctx){
    ctx.reply('foo');
}

bot.command('dit', async (ctx) => {
      await executeAfterGivenTime(() => newOne(ctx), 0);
      await executeAfterGivenTime(() => newTwo(ctx), 6000);
      await executeAfterGivenTime(() => newThree(ctx), 12000);
})
```

Comment: I do get "coo" but I don't get "boo" and "foo".

Comment: Specify what bot library you are using.

Comment: @KevinWelch Telegraf

Answer (score 4):

You have to wrap your `setTimeout` in a `Promise` to get the desired result.

Read the `Promise` docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```js
const executeAfterGivenTime = (func, time) =>
  new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res(func()), time));

function newOne(ctx) {
  ctx.reply("coo");
}

function newTwo(ctx) {
  ctx.reply("boo");
}

function newThree(ctx) {
  ctx.reply("foo");
}

// Dummy bot for testing
const bot = {
  command: (str, fn) => {
    console.log(`Command "${str}" detected. Executing funtion`);
    fn();
  },
};

// Dummy ctx for testing
const ctx = {
  reply: (txt) => {
    console.log(txt);
  },
};

bot.command("dit", async () => {
  await executeAfterGivenTime(() => newOne(ctx), 0);
  await executeAfterGivenTime(() => newTwo(ctx), 6000);
  await executeAfterGivenTime(() => newThree(ctx), 12000);
});
```

Comment: But what if I want to invoke other functions? It's necessary. I tried this one
```
const getValueAfterGivenTime = (value, time) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(value), time))

const botCommand = async(ctx) => {
  await getValueAfterGivenTime(newOne(ctx), 0);
  await getValueAfterGivenTime(newTwo(ctx), 6000);
  await getValueAfterGivenTime(newThree(ctx), 12000);
}


bot.command('dit', ctx => {
    botCommand(ctx);
})
```
And obviously got problems as you can't pass the result of function to setTimeout

Comment: @Christopher It's the same way of solving it with some minor changes. I have updated the answer. Take a look at it and if you still have any questions, add a comment

Comment: all functions have ctx parameter. I tried to change your  executeAfterGivenTime into =>
const executeAfterGivenTime = (func, time, arg) => new Promise(res => setTimeout((arg) => res(func(arg)), time));
with awaits like this:
await executeAfterGivenTime(newOne, 0, ctx);

Which let to only displaying "coo"

Comment: You don't really need to change `executeAfterGivenTime` function. I made some changes to the answer please take a look.

Comment: I've updated the code in my initial msg. So that's how it is in the program. But after run it doesn't go further "coo".

Comment: There is a small change required to your code. You have to change `newOne(ctx)` to `() => newOne(ctx)` and similarly the others function calls too. Look at the answer for reference. Change those 3 and test is again :)

Comment: Nope, nothing changed, hah. (updated initial snipet so you can see how my code looks like).

Comment: Hey Iam not sure what the problem is, I have edited my answer with dummy `bot` and `ctx`. It still works. Maybe you cannot send more than one reply for one single command or something else from your end is going wrong.

Comment: I know it's not that as when I send replies without setTimeout it works. But thanks for your patience and time.